is it available to use component selector options in Angular local library?
i'm creating my own local library.
is it available to use selector options in Angular Local library?
1.i've already created moudle, and imported both parentComp and childComp (declarations, exports.. etc)
2.i tried to use selector of childComp  in parentComp but not having errors during building (says 'lib-childcomp'is not a known element)

any solutions?

chatgpt doesnt helped much though...
